# AJAX request in a looping form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, forms

I was wondering how to make an ajax request separately inside the looping form, which able to send the async delete request when I click the specified row deleted button.
not sure how to allocate the identity when I click the button using jquery.

```
foreach(var item in Model){
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="id" name="id" value="item.id"/>
    <input type="button" id="btn" name="submit" value="Delete"/>
  </form>
}

<script>
  $("#btn").click(function(){
          // alert the id value
      });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with

```
foreach(var item in Model){
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="id" name="id" value="item.id"/>
    <input type="button" class="btn" data-id="item.id" name="submit" value="Delete"/>
  </form>
}

<script>
  $(".btn").click(function(){
    // alert the id value
    alert($(this).attr("data-id"))
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this but it pops up two alerts since I have a parent button for the modal, looks like the bootstrap class start with 'btn' will be affected.

Comment: you can change class name with btn-click or something.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution based on Agus Friasana method:

```
$(".btn").click(function () {
        // to skip the alert from parent modal button
        if ($(this).attr("data-id") != undefined) {
            alert($(this).attr("data-id").toString());
            $.ajax(
                {
                    url: "your url" + $(this).attr("data-id").toString(),
                    type: "DELETE",
                    dataType: "text",
                    success: function () {
                        alert('success');
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('fail')
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    });
```